# Problem with arrow-keys/scrolling in x11vnc

Tags: keyboard, vnc

I'm using x11vnc to connect through a SSH-tunnel to another computer (running Ubuntu 11.10), and experiencing a strange "bug":

When I close the session to the host computer, the host is unable to scroll by continuously holding down the arrow key(s), e.g. in Firefox or in a terminal. Instead the arrow keys will only scroll down a bit, and wait for next key-press. I have checked that they can scroll with the arrow-keys pre-VNC. So far the only solution I've come up with is to restart the computer, which is kind of silly.

I'm guessing that x11vnc is corrupting "something" "somewhere" in X11 input devices.

I'm using these switches with x11vnc on the host:

```
x11vnc -localhost -display :0 -scale 3/4
```

This is slightly annoying, but I fail to see how to correct this "bug". Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

With a bit of help from [this post](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-bugs/2009-January/047244.html), it turned out that I had to add the following to my script, to be run after the VNC-session has been terminated:

```
xset -r
```

This will re-enable the repeating of keypresses.

The reason is, that x11vnc enables -norepeat by default to prevent a common bug, apparently.

A simpler solution would be to run x11vnc with the `-repeat` option, which does the same thing as xset r.